# C# WinForms DateTimePicker Component

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I m using DateTimePicker component. Does is possible tu change format  ? I Want to be YYYY-MM-DD. This componenet default format is MM/DD/YYYY

Thanks . 
I love you Guys :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use [CustomFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx) to specify the format you want. Do be aware that the picker uses the user's regional settings by default for the format, so you might not want to set it yourself (if you care about internationalization).

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the [`CustomFormat` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx) to `yyyy-MM-dd`.
You'll also need to set [`Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.format.aspx) to `Custom`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `Format` must be set to Custom. Defining `CustomFormat` alone doesn't have an apparent effect unless `Format` specifies to use it.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN reference

```
  public void SetMyCustomFormat()
    {
       // Set the Format type and the CustomFormat string.
       dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
       dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy - dddd";
    }
```